# CoordinatorLayout Scrolling and Pinning

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

**I have** : There is **1.** Toolbar, **2.** ViewPager, **3.** TabLayout, **4.** small ViewPager, **5.** ViewPager for Fragment which has RecyclerView :)

[image]

---

**Desired:** When RecyclerView inside **5.** ViewPager at below is scrolled, 1.Toolbar, 3.TabLayout, 4.ViewPager must be pinned and ONLY 2.ViewPager should be scrolled and gone like below:

[image]

---

**Problem:** I can't only pin 2.ViewPager without pinning 1.Toolbar. So it is like, i pin both 1.Toolbar and 2.ViewPager or none of them.

[image]

---

**Question:** How to only hide 2.ViewPager when scrolling?

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayoutFeedNew"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayoutFeedNew"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarFeedNew"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarLogoFeedNew"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/fenerbahce_logo" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerTopFeedNew"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mavi_bg_gradient"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutTabAndSkor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/haberler_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayoutFeedNew"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/genel_haberler_bant"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color_light_gray"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tabLayoutTextAppearance"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/color_white" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPagerSkorFeedNew"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null" />

                <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/circleIndicatorFeedNew"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp"

                    app:fillColor="@color/color_white"
                    app:pageColor="#bbbbbb"
                    app:strokeColor="#bbbbbb" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <com.pordiva.coreproject.component.NonSwipableViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerPostsFeedNew"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/color_white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do/achieve? http://i.stack.imgur.com/y20rH.png a little bit complicated. and you said: `How to only pin 2.ViewPager when scrolling?` on that picture, the `ViewPager-2` has gone.

Comment: Take 3-4-5 out of the AppBarLayout. Pin 1 and make 2 scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarLayoutFeedNew"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarFeedNew"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarLogoFeedNew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/fenerbahce_logo" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerTopFeedNew"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mavi_bg_gradient"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />      
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutTabAndSkor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/haberler_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayoutFeedNew"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/genel_haberler_bant"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color_light_gray"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tabLayoutTextAppearance"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/color_white" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerSkorFeedNew"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null" />

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/circleIndicatorFeedNew"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@null"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"

                app:fillColor="@color/color_white"
                app:pageColor="#bbbbbb"
                app:strokeColor="#bbbbbb" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

<com.pordiva.coreproject.component.NonSwipableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPagerPostsFeedNew"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_white" />
```

Comment: i put last ViewPager inside last LinearLayout, this time scroll flags does not work. if i put last ViewPager after last LinearLayout, then tablayout gets lost

Answer (score 0):

**If** i underestood that correctly, you can use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with this flag:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

Which says:

> Scroll the view and after it Collapsed, exit (or your purpose, hide it
>   after Collapsed).

Here is a good example of how that is working: https://github.com/TheLittleNaruto/SupportDesignExample

Just put your contents into it for after it collapsed, then it will hide or exit that view.i think this is what you were looking for.

---

**EDIT**: use it with your own implementation.

**Or something like this actually:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbarFeedNew"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerTopFeedNew"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp" />

            <!--Perhaps a ViewPager-->

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayoutFeedNew"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerSkorFeedNew"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null" />

           <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/circleIndicatorFeedNew"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@null"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                app:fillColor="@color/color_white"
                app:pageColor="#bbbbbb"
                app:strokeColor="#bbbbbb" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Does not work, i have tried more than 10 combinations :D

Comment: It was working, not sure what is the issue right now :)